# How to creat a sleep loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, sleep

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to make a Loop that will count to 12 but every count it will sleep for 5 seconds, I made it on python like that :

```
import time
start=0
end=12
        while start<end:
        start=start+1
        time.sleep(5)
```

How can I create a Loop like that in Ruby ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it, **sleep** act as wait,

```
for i in 0..12
   p i
   sleep(5)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, and do I need to import any module to use sleep ?

Comment: No, you don't. In Ruby you don't generally need to import any modules for general operations.

Comment: Understood, last question, what's is the p ?

Comment: p used to print, use puts in program which outputs string.

Comment: `p obj` is more or less equivalent to `puts obj.inspect`.